# Recommender Split Returning Empty Dataset

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using a "Split Data" module set to recommender split to split data for training and testing a matchbox recommender. The input data is a valid user-item-rating tuple (for example, 575978 - 157381 - 3) and I've left the parameters for the recommender split as default (0s for everything), besides changing it to a .75 and .25 split. However, when this module finishes, it returns the complete, unsplit dataset for dataset1 and a completely empty (but labelled) dataset for dataset2. This also happens when doing a stratified split using the "Split Rows" mode. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks.

Edit: Including a sample of my data.

```
UserID  ItemID  Rating
835793  165937  3
154738  11214   3
938459  748288  3
819375  789768  6
738571  98987   3
847509  153777  3
991757  124458  3
968685  288070  2
236349  8337    3
127299  545885  3
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you're using?

Comment: @Jon edited my original post to include a sample

Comment: How many rows do you have total? If I added more rows, then the split happened. But with just the sample data I got the same result as you with no data in the second dataset.

Comment: Figured it out. In my "Remove Duplicate Rows" module up the chain a bit I was only removing duplicates by UserID instead of UserID _and_ ItemID. This still left quite a bit of rows but I'm assuming it messed with the stratification. Thanks for being willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In my "Remove Duplicate Rows" module up the chain a bit I was only removing duplicates by UserID instead of UserID *and* ItemID. This still left quite a bit of rows but I'm assuming it messed with the stratification.